# How to display text with angle brackets in innerText of a richtextbox?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, tags, richtextbox

I am reading text from a text file which contains some text inside angle brackets e.g "`<`sometext`>`"
I am using richtextbox (jquery.cleditor.js) to display this text.

```
tbxImgSpellCh.InnerText = text;
```

Text inside angle brackets is missing in richtextbox.

I have tried by changing code to

```
tbxImgSpellCh.InnerHtml = text;
```

But still text inside angle brackets is missing in richtextbox.

I am using htmlEncode to display text in angle brackets

```
text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text);
```

Now text inside angle brackets is shown in richtextbox but the problem is that it also displays other html tags like `<br/>, &nbsp; &amp;` etc.

How to hide other html tags and display text in angle brackets alongwith other text ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line of code in web.config for allowing this characters

```
  <pages validateRequest="false" ></pages>
```

Comment: not working already using <pages validateRequest="false" /> in web.config